# Power plane layers visualization in Altium

Tags: altium

So I set one of the internal layers in a 4-layer board as a "plane" layer and now the border of this layer along with every via and hole is drawn like this:
[image]

As I understand this is the pullback line, but it is really distracting. Is it possible to hide this huge green line without hiding all the polygons? Is this how it is supposed to be?

Thanks

Comment: can you hide that layer from view?

Comment: Just display the signal layers until it's time to carve up a power plane and/or change the color scheme so it's lower contrast and less annoying.